# c# post request how to limit what var of an entity need to be filled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, http-post

I have a post request that gets an entity class (via the url) that I made in my backend there are multiple constructor as in some cases some values won't need to be filled in. how do I make sure that the post request doesn't need to fill in all values of the entity. In my frontend I've made a class that has the same values/name as this entity however when I try to send it I get an error, and when I use swagger to look at all the inputs of the request it is expecting values thatI don't actually want to be filled in (leaving these empty in swagger gives me a 500 error code: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance).

Is there a way of removing these from the request or do they need to be filled in as null.

example (this isn't the actual code, just made as an example of what i mean):

```
public class Person : Entity
{
   long Id {get;set;}
   string name {get;set;}
   string lastName {get;set;}
   DateTime Birth {get;set;}
   DateTime Death {get;set;}
   List<Person> kids {get;set;}

   public Person(){}

   public Person(string name, string lastname, DateTime Birth, DateTime Death, List<Person> kids){
      this.name = name;
      ...
   }
   public Person(string name, string lastname, DateTime Birth){
      this.name = name;
      ...
   }
}
```

There is a request where I would not need to set either death or kids because this person has none and other requests where they would. When filling as null it seems so cause an error even though there is not "contracts.require" on them (leaving these empty in swagger gives me a 500 error code: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance).

Comment: It's a terrible idea to expose your data model to your view binding. This is why each view should have its own model.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid casting POST calls as entities, especially for things like Update (PATCH or PUT) scenarios. The data received is not an entity, it is a set of values, treat it as such.

As far as the entities go, values like "Death" should likely be `Nullable` types as it's probably not expected to be set unless the person is Dead. The simplest way to work with entities is to allow their properties to be `public` letting implementing code update values.

```
public DateTime? Death { get; set; }
```

When it comes to collection references for 1-to-many / many-to-many I recommend initializing these on creation of the class, either via the auto-property or constructor:

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> Kids {get; private set;} = new List<Person>();
```

You will want to avoid "setting" collections. EF entities track relationships and replacing a collection reference after initialization can lead to unexpected behaviour or errors. Whether done externally to the Person class or as a result of a method inside Person other than the constructor, collection references shouldn't be touched, something to  be careful about.

If you want more fine-grained control over updating entities you can use `private` setters and expose methods to validate & perform updates. Similarly for constructing new instances I would recommend having constructors or factory methods that accept all required values (non-null-able) where any optional values can be managed via parameters. The issue then becomes how do you handle cases where you want to update optional values to #null vs. indicate that there is nothing to update. This is where more DDD-style actions can come in, and breaking down actions rather than relying on a CRUD-style API.

For example take the Death property. If we have an UpdatePerson() method that accepts a de-serialized Person with a Null Death value, does that mean the person is alive, or just that we haven't changed a Death date value? If instead we separate update actions so that we have something like:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePersonName(long personId, string firstName, string lastName)
{ }
public ActionResult UpdateDateOfBirth(long personId, DateTime dob)
{ }
public ActionResult MarkPersonAsDeceased(long personId, DateTime dateOfDeath)
{ }
```

Each of these actions can specifically validate the data provided before updating the desired information. This means organizing the UI to provide users relevant actions and capture elements for the relevant data, but this also means these operations can be authorized/validated independently making it also easier to test the underlying logic.

When it comes to updating collections, again it can help to keep these as separate actions. I.e.

```
public ActionResult AddKid(long personId, /*Kid details to add */);
public ActionResult RemoveKid(long personId, long kidId);
```

If you want to save new Kids along with their Parent Person as a single operation then actions like this can update a model state in Session which can be persisted as one unit of work. This will require assigning temporary IDs (I.e. such as Negative Ids) while the new models are in session state to be replaced with real IDs when the rows are written to the database.

Comment: thank you for the indept explenation, I've added the "?" to my var that i want to be nullable and i've changed my request to get class from the body of the request (using [FromBody] Person person), but even when just returning the person to see if it arrives well it seems to alway fill everything in as null even when debugging it's all null even though i don't send it in like that. Would you have any idea what could be causing this i've never had this issue and all my request is doing taking a class from body and returning it, i dont get any errors and swagger tells me i'm getting a code 200

Comment: The thing to check would be what data is being passed in such as if this was a form POST or an Ajax call with a JSON payload etc. Things that can result in null values would be conversion issues if your web method is receiving an object where property names don't match the names of values passed in. Consider adding your controller POST method to your question.

Comment: I tried it out changing private set to set and now that works, so if I want private set i cannot pass the object through and should pass individual values or do i understand this wrong